# django bootstrap dropdown not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am building website based in django. I am using bootstrap dropdown in navbar to collapse navbar on low resolution i.e. mobile view, but on clicking button navbar not getting dropdown.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<nav id="main-menu" class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target=".navbar-cat-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-cat-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="{% url 'home_page' %}">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'contact_page' %}">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as far as I know bootstrap uses its own `javascript` library for doing animated stuff like collapsing and so on. so you need to import their `js` file as well.
put this line below your first `<script>` tag

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

note that because bootstrap js library uses `jquery`, you **must** put this line **below** importing jquery. otherwise it won't work.

Comment: thank you i was using a wrong version of jquery  @Amin.